# iTextSharp: which alignment properties are used in a PdfPCell?

Tags: c#, itext

When I use the alignment of the cell so it works:

```
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Text" , Font));
cell1.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
```

But once the alignment does not work:

```
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
cell1.AddElement(new Phrase("Text 1", Font));
cell1.AddElement(new Phrase("Text 2", Font));
cell1.HorizontalAlignment = 2;
```

The reason?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing *text mode* with *composite mode*.

In the first code snippet, you work in *text mode*. This means that the content of the cell is considered to be text only and the properties of the cell are respected, whereas the properties of the elements added to the cell are ignored.

In the second code snippet, you work in *composite mode*. A cell switches to *composite mode* the moment you use the `AddElement()` method. In this case, the properties of the cell are ignored. Instead the properties of the elements is used.

For instance: in text mode, the content of the cell can only have one type of alignment. In composite mode, you can have a paragraph that is left aligned, a paragraph that is centered, and a paragraph that is right aligned, all in the same cell.

Comment: So, in `Text Mode` one cannot have a cell that has `cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER` + `cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE`. It's one option or the other, not both alignments at the same time?

Comment: In *composite mode* (not *text mode*), any value set for `cell.HorizontalAlignment` will be ignored in favor of the horizontal alignment of the elements in the cell. I didn't say anything about vertical alignment. That's not a property of `Paragraph`, `Image`,...

Answer (score 4):

Now yes, it worked.

```
PdfPCell cell1 = new PdfPCell();
Paragraph p1 = new Paragraph("Text 1", Font);
p1.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Text 2", Font);
p2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

cell1.AddElement(p1);
cell1.AddElement(p2);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ha this answer actually has a code sample that works