# iTextSharp PdfPCell Alignment with Chunk

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

I am creating a PDF programmatically using iTextSharp and generating a PdfPTable.

In some of the cells I need to have a hyperlink.

Without a hyperlink I can align the text in the cell horizontally and vertically, however when I add in the chunk which contain my hyperlink, the cell looses its alignment property.

Here is my code...

```
var webAddress = new Chunk(row["product_code"].ToString(), linkFont);
webAddress.SetAnchor(row["url"].ToString());

PdfPCell ProductCodeCell = new PdfPCell();
ProductCodeCell.AddElement(webAddress);
ProductCodeCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
ProductCodeCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
ProductCodeCell.Padding = 3f;
table.AddCell(ProductCodeCell);
```

Can anyone help me realign the link?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17230600/231316) for a discussion on *Text Mode* versus *Composite Mode*. Basically, if you use `AddElement()` you need to set the alignment on your object instead of the cell itself. `Chunk` doesn't have alignment, however, so you need to wrap your chunk in something that does which is the `Paragraph`.

```
var table = new PdfPTable(1);

//Create our chunk with anchor
var webAddress = new Chunk("hello");
webAddress.SetAnchor("http://www.example.net/");

//Create a paragraph holding the chunk and set the alignment on _it_
var para = new Paragraph(webAddress);
para.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

//Create our cell
PdfPCell ProductCodeCell = new PdfPCell();

//Add the paragrph to it
ProductCodeCell.AddElement(para);

//Padding on the cell still works
ProductCodeCell.Padding = 30f;

//Add cell to table
table.AddCell(ProductCodeCell);
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine on VB.Net too!